# Why does this SQL Case statement return a null in some instances?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, case

I'm using this script to generate some data

```
select case abs(checksum(newid())) % 5 + 1
                    when 1 then 'excellent'
                    when 2 then 'good'
                    when 3 then 'fair'
                    when 4 then 'poor'
                    when 5 then 'failing'
                    end
```

It returns these values: `excellent,good,fair,poor,failing,null`

I assumed I was getting a result outside of `1,2,3,4,5` causing the `null` to return from the case. So I executed this script:

```
select abs(checksum(newid())) % 5 + 1
```

It returns only these values: `1,2,3,4,5`

Assuming I didn't get a 0 or 6 during debugging due to some exceptional statistical phenomenon (because I ran the statement > 100 times), there is some other issue causing this.

Comment: As an aside, `CASE` is an *expression*, not a *statement*. Perhaps a worthwhile read (for these and other reasons): [Dirty Secrets of the CASE Expression](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression).

Answer (score 4):

This occurs because SQL Server generates a new newid() for each when in the case statement.  You can avoid the issue like this:

```
DECLARE @rand TINYINT
SELECT  @rand = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5 + 1

SELECT  CASE @rand
          WHEN 1 THEN 'excellent'
          WHEN 2 THEN 'good'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'fair'
          WHEN 4 THEN 'poor'
          WHEN 5 THEN 'failing'
        END
```